# Is it possible to do a semi-automated test on Cypress that involves solving recaptcha manually?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress, recaptcha, captcha

I know that according to [Cypress Best Practices](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Visiting-external-sites) it's recommended to not test 3rd party apps which are not under one's control, but as a a future tester, I'm asserting my authority by doing so anyway!

So I just wanted to test the `log in` procedure and `POST` response with status `200` for [this particular page](https://bandcamp.com/), so I wrote the following test case here:

```
describe('Log in and Log out Tests', () => {
    
    it('Log in Test', () => {

    /// Go to 'https://bandcamp.com/'
    cy.visit('https://bandcamp.com/')
        
    /// Get the 'log in' element and click it
    cy.get("[class='log-in-link']").click()

    /// Assert the log in page is 'https://bandcamp.com/login'
    cy.url().should('include', '/login')

    /// Set up the API variable, in this case the url was '**/login_cb'
    cy.intercept('POST', '**/login_cb').as('POSTresponse')

    /// Get the 'Username/email' textbox and type the email then verifies such textbox contains the previous 
    cy.get('[name="username-field"]').type('xxxx@outlook.com')
        .should('have.value', 'xxxx@outlook.com')

    /// Get the 'Password' textbox and type the password
    cy.get('[name="password-field"]').type('xyz')
        .should('have.value', 'xyz')

    /// Click the 'Log in' button
    cy.get('#loginform > div.buttons > button').click()

    /// Here comes the human tester that kills the reCaptcha manually IF NEEDED ///

    /// Now wait for the POSTresponse variable
    cy.wait('@POSTresponse')

    /// Print the value of POSTresponse variable as a JQuery object
    cy.get('@POSTresponse').then( XHR => {
        console.log(XHR)
        // Check that the status code is equal to 200 (success)
        expect(XHR.response.statusCode).to.equal(200)
    })

    })

})
```

The thing is, when executing the automated test above, such page sometimes throws a reCaptcha to solve it, sometimes it doesn't, so I would like to know if there's a way to add an if/else exception for such event where the test just literally waits until that reCaptcha gets solved manually (by me), for then executing the rest of code.

Comment: why not intercept the captcha's request and wait till you get a 200? And then 
cy.wait('@googleCaptcha')

Comment: That sounds acceptable, but how would I do that? I mean, which cypress commands are necessary to do so? @EugenSunic

Comment: cy.intercept('googleCatptchaRequest') and cy.wait(), the same you used above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below

> Here comes the human tester that kills the reCaptcha manually IF
> NEEDED

insert

```
cy.intercept('POST' , 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/*').as('googleCaptcha') 
cy.wait('@googleCaptcha').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200)
```